# adding Button on UITtabbar and My button must be higher than TabBar (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm working on `UITabBarController`. And now i want to add `Button` in the middle of `UITabBar`. The problem is my button must be higher than `TabBar`. In other words half of my button is out of `TabBar`. Is it possible? if it is possible, how can i do that?  Thanks.

Comment: take look https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/center-button-in-tab-bar

Comment: thanks, i got useful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cover the UITabBarController with a UIView that has buttons. Use the buttons to programmatically select the correct tab. make the UIView have a clear background and be the height of the tallest button on the bar.

Comment: can you explain more completely

Comment: Basically, somewhere in the app you have a variable which is a UITabBarController. What you'll need to do, is place a UIView over the tab bar, either programmatically or directly from the xib file. Once you have the view, put buttons in it (programmatically or from the xib). Each button will correlate to a TabBarItem (you can tag the buttons with the index of its corresponding tab). Now, add a selector to the button that will look like this : 
- (IBAction) pressedTab : (id) sender {
   int tag = ((UIButton *) sender).tag;
   [myTabBarControlller setSelectedIndex:tag];
}
Hope that's better.